How to get Task Id passed back to Twilio function using plugin
To begin, the work here is based on this write-up for transferring Flex calls back to IVR Flows. https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/transfer-calls-back-to-your-ivr-from-flex
That being said when using the plugin file included in this GitHub https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr/blob/main/src/TwilioFlexTransferToIvrPlugin.tsx
You may notice that it is pulling the task from the props object being passed through to the TransferToIVR function. From that task, it is pulling the relevant call_sid or transferToIvrUrl to get us back to the flow. I need to get the task_sid from this task.
I was thinking I could just add the sid to the Props interface under task. And then when the request is made in OnClick() just pass through that additional value. This is not working as I expected. When logging the event object back in my Twilio function only the call_sid and transferToIVRMenu are shown.

The task SID should already be passed through on the task object, it is assigned to the sid property[1].
If you replace lines 51 to 53 of the flex plugin code [2] with the following code
const {
   sid,
   attributes: { transferToIvrUrl, call_sid },
} = task;

You should be able to use the task sid.
There is also a higher-order component withTaskContext which can also be used when working with tasks.
Hope this helps
Rob
[1] https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/2.1.0/advanced/interfaces/ITask/
[2] https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr/blob/783c1792f84ae97b5c629b7cea2b15da88de0e72/src/TwilioFlexTransferToIvrPlugin.tsx#L51C5-L54C1
[3] https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/add-component-context#add-task-data-to-a-custom-component
